# What are some good starting points to learning about Algorithmic Skeletons?

Tags: algorithm, model, reference

Algorithmic-skeletons, or Parallelism Patterns, are models for programming which hide some or all of the complexity of parallelizing a given program from the programmer who is using them.

Generally, I'm looking to dive deep into these models of programming, and am wondering if there are any good introduction or overview texts/papers I should look at first.

Comment: I never here about it before, but I checked the wiki there is a good article about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should start by looking at the Wikipedia Page, Goole "Wikipedia Algorithmic Skeleton".

After that take a deeper look at the literature through this survey paper:

http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/spe.1026/abstract

Finally I recommend you get your hands on the Skandium Library (Java) to get a feel on how A.S. work:

http://skandium.niclabs.cl

Comment: The github for skandium seems to be a bit more lively than the site, the last release on the site seems to be marked as a beta and is from 2009.

Comment: Yes, the current github code has some additional examples and bug corrections, and will soon be packaged into a release.